# Python os.listdir docstring says "list of files" but directories are also included

Tags: python

In `Python 3.6.4`, According to the docstring of the `os.listdir` method:

```
import os
help(os.listdir)
Help on built-in function listdir in module nt:

listdir(path=None)
    Return a list containing the names of the files in the directory.
...
```

The help states that it returns the list of files in the directory, but actually it also returns the folders not only the files.

Does the docstring need to be corrected?

Comment: Theoretically, a directory [is a file system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_(computing)), but I agree It's confusing. In python2 returns `[...]` **`entries`** `in the directory`

Comment: @Gsk: So theoretically, the method should be: `listfile` !!

Comment: Theoretically it should perhaps be `listentries` but I don't think it's worth changing. Why they changed a perfectly good docstring is a mystery, though.

Comment: looks like it was inadvertently changed in https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/fdaea06d3c0a020c226f26114aad4e58688f0ab3 -- https://bugs.python.org/issue15176

Comment: Alternately, in POSIX you can argue that a directory *is* a file, just not a *regular* file. But I agree, the original docstring was much clearer.

Answer (score 0):

While it might be nice if it was changed, this information isn't necessarily wrong. It likely has its roots in the Unix idiom "Everything is a file", and on Unix-like operating systems directories are also files even if a user doesn't agree with those semantics. Windows does this too. The help for the `dir` command lists "Directory" as a file attribute.

The OS module and filesystem details like this can not be said to be universally cross-platform, but on the filesystems you're most likely to be dealing with today it's worth keeping in mind that files and directories are part of the same hierarchy and there is going to be some equivalence between the two in filesystem APIs.

Comment: I don't care if a directory is a file or not. In python zen it states: `Beautiful is better than ugly`, 
 `Explicit is better than implicit`.
`Simple is better than complex`. `Readability counts.`

Comment: `In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess`. `If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.`

Comment: You're generally going to have to compromise a bit on the philosophy and customs of a programming language to deal with the filesystem. I don't personally think you should apply the zen of Python to the `os` module.